# Spoofing in Seamonkey

Tags: seamonkey

Yahoo mail will no longer work in Seamonkey browsers.

I spoofed mine by adding general.useragent.override;Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0 in about:config.

Is that going to affect my getting Seamonkey updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it shouldn't, as long as your updates are from a repository or PPA and you installed SeaMonkey as a package.  If that's the case, the package will update normally, though you might (or might not) have to recreate your spoof after an update (if only to reflect the newer version to avoid security lockouts).

If you built SeaMonkey from source, or downloaded it as a tarball (.tar.gz or .tar.bz), you'd need to manually update anyway, regardless of spoofing.